# REGULAR language (Automata theory)

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, computation-theory, nfa

**Is it true that the language accepted by any NFA is different from the regular language?** I just started TOC, and someone asked me this question, I'm not sure what it exactly means and how to justify it, i tried googling it, but no results.. can someone help me with this?

Comment: Every NFA has an equivalent DFA, and both accept regular languages.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept and give upvote it to help other people for finding a solution when they have same issue. The majority of people see accepted or upvoted answer.

Comment: My reputation is under 15 as i just started, so my upvote won't be public, regardless, i did upvote ur answer

Answer (score 1):

A language L is called regular if and only if there exists some deterministic finite accepter (DFA) M such that

```
                                       L= L(M)
```

Let L be the language accepted by a non-deterministic finite accepter (NFA) MN= (QN, Σ,δN,q0
,FN). Then
there exists a deterministic finite accepter MD= (QD, Σ,δD,{q0},FD) such that

```
                                       L= L(MD)
```

So we can design at least one `DFA` for one `NFA` and as a result, language of both of them is regular.

You can see more information about it in [An introduction to formal languages and automata Peter Linz](http://almuhammadi.com/sultan/books/Linz.5ed.pdf), section 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

An language accepted by a FA (whatever NFA or DFA)  **is**  Regular Language!

What's more, regular sets, DFA, NFA, pattern, regular expression are equivalent.